# Invoking ASP.NET MVC project URL from a different existing ASP.NET web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have ASP.NET winforms webapplication running in production. For new requirements we would like to go for ASP.NET MVC. We have requirement to go for new project (but same solution).

How do we call ASP.NET MVC application url from existing ASP.NET winforms project URL. There would be a Menu item in existing ASP.NET winforms application, when clicking on the Menu, it should invoke ASP.NET MVC url.

We have explored using IFrames, looking for better solution.

Comment: winforms web application?

Comment: I assume he means Web Forms

Comment: Yes its ASP.NET Web Forms

Answer (score 0):

You can use Querystring with the uniq parameter call the other url.These actions are been Oninit methods.

Forexamp: your mvc project click menu button:

```
 Response.Redirect(test.com+ "?TransferCode=" +TransferCode,false);
```

and other project(asp.net) oninit method catch that

```
var transfercode = Request.QueryString["TransferCode"];
if (transfercode==ok)
{
  welcomesite();
}
```

İt is important that TransferCode value is been known MVC project and asp.net project.

Comment: Why is that required to have trasfercode or any such parameter when moving from ASP.NET WebForms to ASP.NET MVC and vice versa?

Comment: Cookies or session transfers should be used if these two different projects are co-logged
For session transfer, we need to know what the session is on the other project.

Comment: I would have to give a general answer. If these two projects are broadcast on the same server, this can also be done by adding a web config machine key.